# In Visual studio enterprise, How to run the updated coded web test which was generated from recorded web test?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, performance-testing

I am using visual studio enterprise 2015 edition for performance test.I have some recorded web test. I converted the recorded web test in to coded. After conversion  I updated the coded part to handle the session ID.

I want to run the code with updated changes. Is it possible? How? 
Is the updated code changes reflected in the recorded web test? 
How Recorded web test run with updated code changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion of a `.webtest` file to a coded test is a one-way process. After the conversion you have two files that are entirely separate. Changes made to one will not lead to any change in the other.

To run a coded web test, use the "Run coded web performance test" menu entry from the context (right click) menu within the code file. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182552(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hello @DevmatiWadikar if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. For more details please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer